# How to keep empty df's variables while split a list of df

Tags: r

I have a list of df `lst`. I would like to generate an excel file for each subject ID and each file will contain multiple sheets, which equal to the df in lst. So I am creating a list of list by `SubjectID'. And I would like to keep df's variables even when there is no input for that SubjectID.

Currently my codes was able to make new list by SubjectID, and I can have the tab for empty df, but no variables included. Is it a way to include the variables?

For example, for `101-02-102`, currently it looks like:
[image]

I would like to have it as:

[image]

The Visit should looks like this:

[image]

```
lst <- list(Demographics = structure(list(SubjectID = c("101-01-101", 
"101-02-102", "101-03-103"), BRTHDTC = c("1953-07-07", "1963-07-02", 
"1940-09-11"), SEX = c("Female", "Female", "Male")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), DiseaseStatus = structure(list(
    SubjectID = c("101-01-101", "101-02-102"), DSDT = c("2016-03-14", 
    "2017-04-04"), DSDT_P = c(NA_character_, NA_character_)), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), Visits = structure(list(
    SubjectID = c("101-01-101", "101-03-103"), Visit = c("Screening: -28 Days to Day 1", 
    "Screening: -28 Days to Day 1"), VISND = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))

library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
lst1 <- map(lst, ~ .x %>%
              split(.$SubjectID))%>% purrr::transpose(.)
```

Comment: If i understand correctly, `lst` has dataframes like Demographics, Visits etc, you want to create an excel file for `lst` with multiple sheets where each sheet equal to dataframes within the sheet. Some of the dataframes might be empty but you still want to have a sheet for them?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am wanting

Comment: I am thinking of when a df is NULL, then replace it with empty df. But how to make it automatically. Will that be too silly to go this route? Is there any way that it is simpler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
library(tidyverse)
map2(lst, bind_rows(lst) %>%
  distinct(SubjectID) %>%
  list(), ~full_join(.x, .y, 'SubjectID') %>%
         split(~SubjectID)) %>%
  transpose()
```

For an empty dataframe/tibble:

```
library(tidyverse)

d <- bind_rows(lst) %>%  
  distinct(SubjectID)  %>%
  unlist(use.names = FALSE)

map(lst, ~ {
  a <- slice(.x, 0)
  .x %>%
      split(.$SubjectID)%>%
      `[`(d) %>%
      set_names(d) %>%
    modify_if(is.null, ~a)}) %>%
  transpose()
```

The above code can also be written as:

```
d <- unique(unlist(map(lst, ~.x$SubjectID)))
map(lst, ~modify_if(split(.x, .$SubjectID)[d], is.null, ~slice(.y, 0), .y=.x)%>%
          set_names(d))%>%
  transpose()
```

Result:

```
$`101-01-101`
$`101-01-101`$Demographics
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  SubjectID  BRTHDTC    SEX   
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr> 
1 101-01-101 1953-07-07 Female

$`101-01-101`$DiseaseStatus
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  SubjectID  DSDT       DSDT_P
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr> 
1 101-01-101 2016-03-14 NA    

$`101-01-101`$Visits
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  SubjectID  Visit                        VISND
  <chr>      <chr>                        <chr>
1 101-01-101 Screening: -28 Days to Day 1 NA   


$`101-02-102`
$`101-02-102`$Demographics
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  SubjectID  BRTHDTC    SEX   
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr> 
1 101-02-102 1963-07-02 Female

$`101-02-102`$DiseaseStatus
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  SubjectID  DSDT       DSDT_P
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr> 
1 101-02-102 2017-04-04 NA    

$`101-02-102`$Visits
# A tibble: 0 x 3
# ... with 3 variables: SubjectID <chr>, Visit <chr>, VISND <chr>


$`101-03-103`
$`101-03-103`$Demographics
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  SubjectID  BRTHDTC    SEX  
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr>
1 101-03-103 1940-09-11 Male 

$`101-03-103`$DiseaseStatus
# A tibble: 0 x 3
# ... with 3 variables: SubjectID <chr>, DSDT <chr>, DSDT_P <chr>

$`101-03-103`$Visits
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  SubjectID  Visit                        VISND
  <chr>      <chr>                        <chr>
1 101-03-103 Screening: -28 Days to Day 1 NA
```

Comment: @Stataq are you trying this code on your example above? It works.

Comment: Do i need to change anything in order to run?

Comment: @Stataq not really, unless you are using R<4 which means you need to change `split(~SubjectID)` into `split(.$SubjectID)`

Comment: Yes, I am using 3.6.3. :P Currently it input ID to the empty  df. Is it possible to keep it as blank? So people won't mistakenly think it has record in it? Thinking of length of none NA=1, then remove all records. But how to do that?

Comment: That is very clever way! Could you explain a little more on  `slice` and the use of  ``[`(d) `

Comment: @Stataq. Try `slice(iris, 0)` this will give you an empty dataframe from iris. The notion of `[` comes from the idea that if I have a list, then extracting an element that does not exist in the list will give me null. I then modify the null elements to contain the empty dataset

Comment: @Stataq check the edit for a cleaner code

Answer (score 1):

You can `merge` a subjects' data frame to all data frames, using `all=TRUE` yields `NA`'s where ID is missing, which is excatly what you want.

```
subjects <- data.frame(SubjectID=sort(unique(unlist(lapply(lst, `[[`, 'SubjectID')))))

lst1 <- lst %>%
  map(merge, subjects, all=TRUE) %>%
  map(~ .x %>% split(.$SubjectID)) %>%
  purrr::transpose(.)

lst1$`101-02-102`
# $Demographics
# SubjectID    BRTHDTC    SEX
# 2 101-02-102 1963-07-02 Female
# 
# $DiseaseStatus
# SubjectID       DSDT DSDT_P
# 2 101-02-102 2017-04-04   <NA>
#   
#   $Visits
# SubjectID Visit VISND
# 2 101-02-102  <NA>  <NA>
```